# How to set a dynamically retrieved image as a background image by using css

Tags: django

in my template, I'd need to set a dynamically retrieved image as a background image by using css

```
background-image: url('{% static <image_path> %}')
```

where

```
<image_path> = {{ instance.image }}
```

Any hint more then welcome!

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. That should work (in a `style` attribute).

Comment: are you uploading it and saving in the database?

Comment: thank you for your replies, I've found the mistake.. I was trying to retrieve the image in the wrong folder, not `static/` but `media`. Sorry if I made you loose time!!

Answer (score 0):

My (silly) mistake, I was trying to retrieve the image in the wrong folder.

Now it works.